# common exit status to python,bash,tcl scripts

Tags: python, bash, tcl

"""i have a framework that calls python,bash,tcl modules ,each module should end with some common exit status SUCCESS=0,FAILURE=1.the framework has to catch it and interpret it ,how can i do that.
i thought of declaring a class and importing this class in all the modules 
but how can i import into tcl and bash modules
"""

util.py

```
class returncode:
  success=0
  failure=1
```

script.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
. ../../util.py
catch_error("error","plugin")
```

while sourcing it shows error:

```
 ./../util.py: line 1: from: command not found
../../util.py: line 2: import: command not found
../../util.py: line 5: $'\nall the common utility functions for harness and plugins are provided in this module\n': command not found
../../util.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
../../util.py: line 6: `def platform():'
./sample.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `"vam","Dada"'
./sample.sh: line 4: `catch_error("error","plugin")'
```

Comment: Python, shell, and Tcl are three separate langauges; you can't import the same code into all three.

Comment: It _might_ be possible to write a polyglot script that did that, but why would you bother (except to show off)? It serves no practical purpose to do that sort of trick.

Comment: More usefully, are these modules being run within a single process or as subprocesses?

Comment: they are run as subprocesses@DonalFellows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every language describes things differently. It's effectively a non-starter to use the same file as source code for more than one language at once (it can be done, but it's hard work and not worth it). You *don't* import things from one language into another without really complicated inter-lingual shims, and they're best avoided when doing simple things.

But different languages can do *equivalent* operations. This is relevant to you.

In your case, you should be aware that the concepts of successful and failing executions you're working with are exactly the standard ones (except that there are many other possible ways to fail, and so many non-zero exit codes that are legal) which means that code can be very simple indeed.
In each case, I list both the code for exiting successfully and for exiting with a failure. In each case, it turns out that the default exit code is zero; code only has to say more to use a non-zero code.

Sometimes these will look very similar (the Tcl and Bash code below). ***Do not think they are the same!*** They just might be tiny pieces that look alike; a larger program most definitely will not be the same. This just happens to be one of the places where there are similarities. Adding anything extra (like trivial conditional execution) would make the syntaxes look quite different.

## Python

```python
import sys
# Exit with code for success (default)
sys.exit()
```

```python
import sys
# Exit with code for failure
sys.exit(1)
```

## Tcl

```tcl
# Exit with code for success (default)
exit
```

```tcl
# Exit with code for failure
exit 1
```

## Bash

```bash
# Exit with code for success (default)
exit
```

```bash
# Exit with code for failure
exit 1
```